# iOS: How to understand that all views changed orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I need to get the size of my custom UIView after changing orientation.
I tried to catch UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification but, as I understand, I get this notification just after device orientation has been changed. However all views need a little more time to rebuild itself in new orientation so when I try to get size just by UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification I get the wrong values. When I add some delay it works fine.
Could you tell me some best practice to do what I want?

**Update 2015-01-12**
Ok, I try to do it with - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
But it doesn't help I get 0 at CGFloat chartWidth = self.webView.frame.size.width

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if (self.orientationChangedFlag == YES)     //orientation was changed
    {
        CGFloat chartWidth = self.webView.frame.size.width; 
        CGFloat chartHeight = self.webView.frame.size.height;

        self.orientationChangedFlag = NO;
    }
}
```

But I see the big size of webView on the screen in device emulator.

Comment: Why do you need to read this size after rotation? Try building your layout using autoresizing masks or autolayout. There is also a method didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: Unfortunately I had believed in iOS8 size class and now I found out that it has not support for iPad in Landscape only, just iPad in Landscape/Portrait and now I have to do this weird things... ((( Arrrr...